# How to update data with 3 join from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a task to do: update `commission_pct` in table `Employees` (depends on table `Departments`) with the following conditions: Notes – Max Salary can gain from table Jobs.

Department Name - commission_pct

- Administration  -  Max_Salary * 5%
- Marketing - Max_Salary * 10%
- Purchasing - Max_Salary * 15%
- Finance - Max_Salary * 25%
- Shipping - Max_Salary * 15%
- IT        - Max_Salary * 25%

This the `EMPLOYEES` table:

[image]

This is the `DEPARTMENTS` table:

[image]

This is the `JOBS` table:

[image]

I already wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
    DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
    JOBS.MAX_SALARY
FROM 
    EMPLOYEES
INNER JOIN 
    DEPARTMENTS ON EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    JOBS ON EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID = JOBS.JOB_ID
         AND DEPARTMENT_NAME IN ('Administration', 'Marketing',
                                 'Purchasing', 'Finance',
                                 'Shipping', 'IT')
GROUP BY 
    DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID, JOBS.MAX_SALARY
```

and the result of this query looks like this:

[image]

I don't know how to update it, I am confused as to how to update with specific departments.

Comment: im not able to understand the question . Can you please try to clearify a bit more or give example of the final intended ouput

Answer (score 0):

You need to run an `update` statement with an `inner join` as below:

```
update e
set commission_pct = 
case when d.DEPARMENT_NAME = 'Administration' THEN j.MAX_SALARY * 0.05
when d.DEPARMENT_NAME = 'Marketing' THEN j.MAX_SALARY * 0.1
when d.DEPARMENT_NAME = 'Purchasing' THEN j.MAX_SALARY * 0.15
when d.DEPARMENT_NAME = 'Finance' THEN j.MAX_SALARY * 0.25
when d.DEPARMENT_NAME = 'Shipping' THEN j.MAX_SALARY * 0.15
when d.DEPARMENT_NAME = 'IT' THEN j.MAX_SALARY * 0.25
else 0
end

from Employees as e
inner join department as d on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
inner join jobs as j on e.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID
```

This will leave a `NULL` where the employee's `JOB_ID` is not listed in the `JOBS` table.

Answer (score 0):

The update query looks a bit different because of the aggregation.  You need to handle that in a subquery or CTE:

```
update j
    set min_salary = ed.min_salary,
        max_salary = ed.max_salary
    from jobs j join
         (select e.job_id, min(e.salary) as min_salary, max(e.salary) as max_salary
          from employees e join
               departments d
               on d.department_id = e.department_id
          where d.department_name in ('Administration', 'Marketing', 'Purchasing',
                                      'Finance', 'Shipping', 'IT'
                                     )
          group by e.job_id
         ) ed;
```